# What is the format for a Snakemake JSON config file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, yaml, snakemake

I can find examples of yaml config files, but I can't find any json config files, and my guesses are failing

How do I do this in a JSON config file, such that config["samples"] will return the correct values?

```
Yaml:
samples:
    A: data/samples/A.fastq
    B: data/samples/B.fastq
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `config.yaml` that looks like this:

```yaml
samples:
    A: data/samples/A.fastq
    B: data/samples/B.fastq
```

Then the equivalent `config.json` will look like this:

```json
{
    "samples":
    {
        "A": "data/samples/A.fastq",
        "B": "data/samples/B.fastq"
    }
}
```

So the following `Snakefile` will have the same behaviour with `yaml` or `json` configfile:

```py
# uncomment the option of interest
# configfile: 'config.json'
# configfile: 'config.yaml'

rule all:
    input:
       A=config['samples']["A"],
       B=config['samples']["B"]
```

Note that the failure of the Snakefile above is intended, it will show that the contents of the configfile were parsed correctly.